# Unhide a EFI System partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, uefi

I don't know how I come to this but the partition I use to install Windows 7 64-bit is hidden. It is also a EFI System partition (I saw this using the Disk Management tool).

Since the Windows partition is hidden, I cannot boot into it and also can not repair.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: I am confused here. How is it hidden?  Since you mentioned EFI it should be a GPT partitioned disk and a EFI system partition. Those are compativle with FAT32 and windows 7 supports  FAT32. SO access should just work. Worst case it can be accessed but is not mounted.  Can you add precisely what happens?

Comment: It appears the OP somehow installed Windows to the ESP. While theoretically possible, this is not a supported scenario with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other OS installed on your system which you can boot into? If yes, then for Windows OS, download and install [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) (or any other partition manager that allows editing partition flags), and in it, right click the partition you want to unhide (Windows 7 partition), go to "Modify" > select "Unhide patition".
For Linux OS, get [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php), and remove "hidden" flag of your Windows 7 partition.

In case you do not have any OS to boot into, get [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) by some way, burn the ISO to disk, boot your system to GParted Live disk, and remove "hidden" flag of your Windows 7 partition.

Answer (score 1):

Using DiskPart you can unhide an EFI partition on a GPT volume:

```
Diskpart>
list volume
select volume #
detail partition
set id=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
```

The default GPT ID for a `EFI System partition` is `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b`, converting to a `Basic data partition` with the ID `...C7` automatically unhides the partition.

I have had success with this command prior, but I believe it was for MBR (msdos) partition table.

```
attributes volume clear hidden
```

Failure to change the partition type before clearing the hidden attribute, results in this diskpart error message:

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.
```

You most likely want to set the ID back to EFI when you are done (eg: modifying BCD)

```
set id=c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
```

Comment: For some reason, os-uninstaller (part of boot-repair-disk) changed my Windows 10 main partition into an EFI System Partition, preventing Windows from booting. Applying these steps made Windows immediate start booting successfully.