# How do I convert an EFI System Partition into a normal GPT partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, uefi, gpt, efi

I had a Windows 8.1 that required a re-install. In the process, my 4TB secondary disk is now showing up in Disk Management as an EFI System Partition, with no volume.

In DISKPART, a volume *is* shown, with the info as "Hidden".

In MiniTool Partition Wizard the volume is shown as an EFI System Partition, but it's NOT listed as hidden. Using the tools in that software, I can successfully browse the data, etc. I've tried hiding, then unhiding the partition, without success.

So, my question is:

How can I convert this EFI System Partition back into an ordinary data partition that I can access and use?

([Unhide a EFI System partition](https://superuser.com/questions/464860/unhide-a-efi-system-partition) doesn't help because my partition isn't flagged as hidden.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, I discovered you can use gdisk from the [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html) suite.

For the benefit of others, use `gdisk 0:` (substitute the number of the affected drive). Type `p` to print the list of partitions. The EFI System Partition will have a type of `EF00`. Enter `t` to change the type, select the number of the partition, and then type the code for the standard Windows partition, which is `0700`. `w` will then write the changes, and after a reboot you should be back to normal.