# My 3TB HD converted to EFI Partition

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, efi

I have 3TB HD installed in my pc. I dont know how its converted to "EFI system partition" !! Can I return it back to normal patition without formating or cleaning it?
 [image: DiskManage] 
This picture shows that disk 0 is completly an EFI partition

Comment: Was it a single partition before? Do you know what kind of filesystem (FAT32, NTFS, ...) it is? Also: Stuff like that doesn’t happen by itself. Did you try to install an operating system?

Comment: yes it was single NTFS partiton. No i didnt try to install any OS. Its really a strange thing !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be as simple as changing the partition type back to “Microsoft Basic data partition” (ID `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7`). This could be accomplished easily with a number of partition tools on Linux:

## `fdisk` (newer GPT-capable versions)

1. Identify disk: `fdisk -l`
2. Start editing: `fdisk /dev/sdX`, where `sdX` is the correct disk as identified in step 1
3. Change type: `t`<kbd>↵</kbd>, `L`<kbd>↵</kbd>, enter code for “Microsoft basic data” from list (`11` on my machine), <kbd>↵</kbd> (nb: because there is only a single partition, we won’t be asked which partition to use)
4. Save changes: `w`<kbd>↵</kbd>

## `gdisk`

1. Identify disk: Run `gdisk -l /dev/sda`, `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`, ... until you find the disk
2. Start editing: `gdisk /dev/sdX`, where `sdX` is the correct disk as identified in step 1
3. Change type: `t`<kbd>↵</kbd>, `L`<kbd>↵</kbd>, enter code for “Microsoft basic data” (`0700` on my machine), <kbd>↵</kbd> (nb: because there is only a single partition, we won’t be asked which partition to use)
4. Save changes: `w`<kbd>↵</kbd>, `y`<kbd>↵</kbd>

## `parted`

1. Identify disk: Run `parted -l`
2. Start editing: `parted /dev/sdX`, where `sdX` is the correct disk as identified in step 1
3. Change type: `toggle 1 msftdata`<kbd>↵</kbd> (nb: changes take effect immediately)
4. Quit: `quit`<kbd>↵</kbd>

You could also use the `file` command to try and determine if it’s still NTFS:

```
file -s /dev/sdX1
```

All of the above needs to be run as root.

If you don’t have a live-bootable Linux available, I recommend using a lightweight image like [Gentoo’s minimal install](https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/) (boots directly to terminal, recommended) or [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why nobody mentioned of the Windows-builtin `diskpart` when talking about changing the partition type GUID:

```
select disk 0
select partition 1 [Could be partition 2 because there is a (hidden) MSR partition before it]
set id=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
```

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)

or

```
set id=7
```

if it is an MBR disk.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a partition recovery software. I would suggest [Test Disk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which is free and reliable.

Also, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/866830/320067) may be useful for you.